# Org-mode: Disable `t` + `TAB` => `# TODO: ` autocomplete feature

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, yasnippet

There is a built-in org-mode shortcut where a `t` character followed by `TAB` key results in an auto-complete function that produces the `# TODO:` string literal. How can I disable this? Even better, how can I look up the function/key-binding that is called when this org-mode shortcut occurs so I can disable similar auto-complete functions from getting called?

I am aware of the `C-h k` and `C-h f` commands, but this is not a normal key-binding and I don't know what the function is called.

I would like to disable this shortcut because I find it annoying, especially when tabbing through org-mode tables.

Comment: Are you sure that's built in to `org-mode`?  I don't get any such behavior after `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 6):

It's a snippet, activated with `yasnippet`. Notice how it starts with a comment character, this hinted to me that it wasn't an `org-mode` feature. Why would `org-mode` comment out a todo?

I have something similar that I got from [this](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet) snippet repository, but it only works in modes derived from `prog-mode` (which excludes `org-mode`). However, the snippets directory is actually a git submodule, and if you inspect *that* repository, you find a commit called "Split text snippets into prog and fundamental". The commit message:

> None of the text-mode snippets were actually specific to text-mode;
>   fixme, todo, and xxx were for making comments, those were moved to
>   prog-mode.

So it seems like you're using an old version of that submodule repo.

To change this, either delete the snippet file (simply named "todo"), or change the key that activates it.

Answer (score 2):

```
M-x find-function-on-key  RET
```

then, `TAB` keypress will take you to the function that plays spoilsport in org-mode.

Comment: This is a suggestion for how to investigate the problem, rather than an answer.  Could you please switch it to a comment?

Comment: To be fair, the question does include the more general question of how to track down the binding.